# RoR - Account - Login - Register + 

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication

Is there an automatic way in Ruby On Rails for authentication porpose?

What gem is this and what does it do?

Does it automaticly generate the tables and pages like when i should generate a scaffold?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are some plugins that do code generation for you, but I strongly prefer [Authlogic](http://github.com/binarylogic/authlogic). Ryan Bates has an excellent [introductory video](http://railscasts.com/episodes/160-authlogic).

Comment: If i want to include a user's adress in the registration form, do i add this in the code of authlogic? 
eg.:
script/generate nifty_scaffold user username:string email:string password:string address:string new edit ?

Answer (score 1):

I agree that Authlogic is a great choice for Rails authentication.

In addition to the links Alex provided, check out the [authlogic_example Git repository](http://github.com/binarylogic/authlogic_example) for step-by-step setup instructions, including the proper migration to be using.  You can still start with nifty_scaffold and then edit the migration, models, and controllers appropriately.

Comment: If you're looking for a new authentication solution these days, I'd highly recommend [Devise](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise). It's the new standard.